# Laravel validation unique email not working on register

Tags: laravel, validation, unique

I am making a register API using Laravel 9. I am trying to make Validator and put email on the unique index. The email column in the 'users' table is set on the unique index. But the unique validation is not working correctly, and it returns blank and no responses when passing the Validator.

```
$validator = Validator::make(
    $data,
    [
        'name' => 'required|min:4|regex:/^[a-zA-Z_ ]*$/',
        'email' => [
            'required',
            'email',
            Rule::unique('users', 'email')
        ],
        'password' => 'required|min:6'
    ]
);

$validated = $validator->validated();

if ($validator->fails()) :
    return throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json([
        'code' => 403,
        'message' => 'Validasi gagal!',
        'data' => $validator->errors(),
    ], 403));
endif;
```

First, I register using "admin@mail.com" and its success. But, the second time I'm using admin@mail.com, the Validator doesn't throw any error. Then, when I'm trying to delete the unique rule, the Validator works again. So, am I making any mistakes?

Comment: `But the unique validation are not working properly, it return blank and no responses when passing the validator` <<<=== can you explain that one a bit more? Blank responses in the browser? What does the network tab of your Google Chrome then say? And your Laravel.log? Try starting to debug. Maybe with try/catch

Comment: If you are working in an API, I would recommend to use FormRequest instead validating directly in your controller. In that way, you will get default 422 laravel error without the need to return a custom exception

Comment: @UnderDog, I'm sorry, forgot to put the explanation. I'm testing the API using Postman, and when i try to passed the exact same data, the validation fails, only show blank response.

Comment: as was previously already said the last time this question was asked, you are not returning anything when validation does not fail [in the code you are showing] ... so you get a blank response because you are not returning anything ..... also what **is not** working about the validation that you mentioned?

Comment: Blank response in *Postman*, so Chek out the blank white box. It has a green line in it with the statuscode. Show that code. `return throw new HttpResponseException` <<<=== that is not correct, you need to throw the exception. Also: check out your laravel.log, it should have had an error

Comment: You either return a json response with 403 status code or throw an exception. You are not supposed to return an exception. Remove the `return` before the `throw`

Comment: @lagbox as i write in my question, i do registering exactly same data. So I'm expecting the validation fail and throw an exception. But i got no response / failing responses.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the built in unique rule `'unique:users,email'`

```php
$validator = Validator::make(
            $data,
            [
                'name' => 'required|min:4|regex:/^[a-zA-Z_ ]*$/',
                'email' => [
                    'required',
                    'email',
                    'unique:users,email'
                ],
                'password' => 'required|min:6'
            ]
        );

        $validated = $validator->validated();

        if ($validator->fails()) :
            return throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json([
                'code' => 403,
                'message' => 'Validasi gagal!',
                'data' => $validator->errors(),
            ], 403));
        endif;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just try this code. And nothing changed. When i test the endpoints using Postman, it still get blank response

Comment: Keep explaining blank response, see my comment to your original question